# Como popular um dicionário dinamicamente com chave e valor?

Tags: python, dicionário

Escreva um programa que recebe um valor inteiro n e retorna um dicionário onde as chaves são números de 1 a n e os valores são os quadrados de suas respectivas chaves.

Ex: para n = 8, o resultado deve ser {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}.

Minha tentativa:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))

list = []

for x in range(1,n+1):

  list.append(x**2)

print(list)
```

Porém, não consegui colocar essa lista no modo dicionário.

Answer (score 4):

Você declarou uma lista e nao um dicionario. Dicionario é declarado com {}

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))

dicionario = {}

for x in range(1,n+1):

  dicionario[x] = x ** 2

print(dicionario)
```

Comment: Ahh, compreendi!!
Muito Obrigada!

Answer (score 4):

Para resolver esta questão você deve implementar um dicionário - cujos delimitadores são **{}** - e não uma lista - cujos delimitadores são **[]**.

Uma das forma que podes utilizar é **[dictionary comprehensions PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)**.

Utilizando esta técnica podemos montar o seguinte código:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
dicionario = {i: i ** 2 for i in range(1, n + 1)}

print(dicionario)
```

Observe que quando executamos o referido código devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A partir desse momento o bloco `for` irá percorrer o **range(1, n + 1)** e para cada interação, será adicionado **i** à chave e o **quadrado de i** ao valor da chave.

Posteriormente será exibido o dicionário devidamente montado.

**Testando o código**

Imagine que queiramos listar os **8 primeiros quadrados perfeitos**. Para isso, ao executar o código devemos digitar...

```
8
```

...e, em seguida, pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Imediatamente o código irá realizar os cálculos e nos exibirá como resultado:

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seguindo o seu raciocínio ainda é possível chegar ao resultado pretendido.
O que faltou ao seu código foi apenas enumerar a lista de quadrados obtida e construir o dicionário em cima dessa enumeração.

Para enumerar um [iterável](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) use o método embutido [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que devolve um objeto enumerado que é apenas um conjunto de [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) de pares onde cada elemento da tupla tem a estrutura `(n + start, iterable[n])`, onde `n` é índice do elemento dentro do iterável.

Para criar um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) use o método embutido [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) que pode a partir de uma sequência de pares criar um dicionário.

```
#Faz o tratamento de exceções caso o usuário digite algo que não seja um número.
while(True):
  try:
    n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))
    break;
  except:
    pass
  
l = []

for x in range(1,n+1):
  l.append(x**2)

d = dict(enumerate(l,start=1))

print(d)
#Digite o valor de n:8
#{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}
```

Note que troquei o nome da sua lista por `l` pois em python existe um uma função embutida cujo o identificador é [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-list) e ao o sobrescrever seu código perde a sua funcionalidade.

Outras formas de obter o mesmo resultado:

Usando um [generator](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#index-19):

```
while(True):
  try:
    n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))
    break;
  except:
    pass

g = (x**2 for x in range(1, n+1))
d = dict(enumerate(g, start=1))

print(d)
#Digite o valor de n:10
#{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

Usando os método [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) e [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
#Faz o tratamento de exceções caso o usuário digite algo que não seja um número.
while(True):
  try:
    n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))
    break;
  except:
    pass

z = zip(r:= range(1, n+1), map(lambda x:x**2, r)) 
d = dict(enumerate(z, start=1))

print(d)
#Digite o valor de n:20
#{1: (1, 1), 2: (2, 4), 3: (3, 9), 4: (4, 16), 5: (5, 25), 6: (6, 36), 7: (7, 49), 8: (8, 64), 9: (9, 81), 10: (10, 100), 11: (11, 121), 12: (12, 144), 13: (13, 169), 14: (14, 196), 15: (15, 225), 16: (16, 256), 17: (17, 289), 18: (18, 324), 19: (19, 361), 20: (20, 400)}
```